# Position fixed when scroll down hopping when the screen is not very big

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make my header fixed when the user scroll down. The problem is if the content on the page is not big enough the screen hopping. Also when I scroll to the top again it change from fixed to normal very hard. Can someone help me with this?

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('.sticky-wrapper').removeClass('stickynow');
} else {
    $('.sticky-wrapper').addClass('stickynow');
}
});
```

Comment: How are you positioning your non-header content?  From my pov, the "smoothest" you can get it would be to have it sticky all the time, and position your content so that it starts after the header, so nothing will jump around.  Also doing that you wouldn't need any of this javascript either.

Comment: I need to do it with javascript.

Comment: Why?  You are effectively making the header sticky when there is *any* scrolling, and taking it off when there is none.  But a sticky header without scrolling looks just the same as a non-sticky header.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what 'screen hopping' means, but i guess what happens is that when your header becomes `position:fixed`, it doesn't occupy space anymore so the `content` moves up to fill that space an thus, 'hopping'.

You should add margin-top to your content ( or whichever element is right after the header in HTML structure ) equal to the header's height.

See below

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let header = $('.sticky-wrapper')
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $(header).removeClass('stickynow');
    $('section').css({
      'margin-top': 0
    })
  } else {
    $(header).addClass('stickynow');
    $('section').css({
      'margin-top': $(header).height()
    })
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.stickynow {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

section {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="sticky-wrapper"></header>
<section>Not 'Hopping'</section>
```

OPTION B. Without javascript/jQuery

If you don't need to add a class or something else that involves javascript/jQuery, you can have the same result as above, but only with css

```css
header {
   position: fixed;
  background: blue;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
}

section {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  margin-top:100px; /*add this*/
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="sticky-wrapper"></header>
<section>Not 'Hopping'</section>
```